# Opening submenu depending on the selected page

Tags: php, menu

I am currently designing a vertical drop menu (with submenus), here's how it looks:

[Click here to see the screenshot](http://img228.imageshack.us/img228/9216/menuamaf.png)

On the left, no menu item is selected.
On the middle and on the right there are sub-menus opened (and the selected page in blue).
One sub-menu can be opened at once (one opens => the other closes).
The contents of the menu is not dynamic.

The big problem was that when i opened a new page, the sub-menu of the selected page had to be opened.

So I decided that all my pages links will be like `index.php?p=my_selected_page` and in a file `menu.php` I built this array:

```
$menu = array(
    'Présentation' => array(
        'accueil' => 'Accueil',
        'inscription' => 'Inscrivez-vous'
    ),
    'Nos actions' => array(
        'mediation-familiale' => 'Médiation familiale',
        'droit-de-visite' => 'Droit de visite accompagnée',
        'accompagnement-familial' => 'Accompagnement familial'
    )
    // [...]
);
```

Then I get the page `$_GET ['p']`. I look through the array and writes the menu html match.
If `$_GET['p']` is one of the key sub-array, I display the sub-menu with a CSS class so that this menu is open.
(And the link is selected by default).

While this solution works, this system only allows me to store links like `index.php?p=my_selected_page`.

I wish I could put other links, like `forum.php` (and include `menu.php` in `forum.php`), etc..

If you have any ideas to make this possible, I would be grateful.

(I am French. Sorry for spelling mistakes.)

Comment: Hotlink to image is here: http://img228.imageshack.us/img228/9216/menuamaf.png

Comment: Thank you. I thought I had copied the right link.

Comment: ImageShack never lets you have the right link. Ever...

Comment: I used firebug to access the disabled input :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]` to ask for the name of your script file, and then do the verification with that information, not sending a variable via GET. :)

e.g.

```
<?php

$script_file = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"];
$no_slashes = explode('/', $script_file);
$script_file = $no_slashes[count($no_slashes) - 1]; 

echo $script_file;

?>
```

At this point, you will have the filename stored in `$script_file`, and you could match it with your array's keys.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your questions seems very comfusing,you may be can try jquery add some javascript click event.
on the other hand, I think if you can use the framework, means inclue all your header

Comment: I already use jQuery for navigation between the sub menus (slideUp/Down, toggle/removeClass ...). I now need another way to manage links other than `"index.php?p=selected_page"`.